# The date on which a reservation was created vs on which a reservation is valid

Tags: expressions, nouns, dates

A reservation can have two dates. The first is the date on which the reservation was created, e.g. July 1. The second is the date on which the reservation is valid, e.g. July 2

On July 1, I made a reservation for July 2 for Room 208.

I'm looking for two concise noun phrases that signify these two dates.

"Date of Reservation" sounds like the latter.

Context: I'm designing a webpage which displays information for a given reservation.

[Noun phrase needed]: July 1

[Noun phrase needed]: July 2

Of course from the dates, one can deduce the meaning of the phrases. However, it is still useful to have easily understandable noun phrases.

Comment: "Date of Reservation" is the "booking date," the other is the "Date of Journey" (in case of travel booking).

Comment: I would think that the first is the _Reservation Date_ while the second is the _check-in date_.  _Booking Date_ (suggested by Kris) also sounds good for the date the reservation is made.

Answer (score 2):

> Date of Reservation

The problem with this is that it can be taken in an ambiguous fashion.

Is it the date when the reservation was *written down*, or the date when the reservation will be *effective*?

The phrasing should be made more explicit in order to take this distinction into account and prevent the wrong interpretation.

Something like:

> 1. Date when the reservation was taken.
> 2. Effective date of the reservation.

You mentioned it needing to be concise, which these phrases are not. But, if on a website, it could be structured in such a way:

> Reservations
>
> - Recorded Date:
> - Effective Date:

Here, "recorded date" is not quite as unambiguous as "date when the reservation was taken," but its meaning can be inferred by virtue of it being in contrast to "effective date."

An alternative to "recorded date" is "date taken," if you don't mind the two not having a parallel structure.